# LSI HBA Enable Partial or Slumber Low Power Mode

Tags: raid, sata, storage, sas

I have a SATA disc connected to a [LSI 9207-8i HBA](https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/host-bus-adapters/sas-9207-8i)
which uses the [LSI SAS2308](https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/sas-sata-controllers/sas-2308) controller. I am trying to put this disc in slumber by enabling device initiated power management. Disk sends a `PMREQ_P` / `PMREQ_S` after issuing the command but the HBA responds with `PMNAK`.

The LSI 2308 Controller Product Brief features lists 
- *Slumber and Partial power mode support for SAS and SATA devices*

The firmware on LSI HBA is version 19 IT (Initiator Target Mode). Is there a setting on the LSI HBA, allowing the drive to go into partial or slumber low power modes?